# Is it better to store public/private keys into variables or read the PEM files?

Tags: php, performance, pem

I'm trying to understand if there's a benefit from copy/pasting the content of my keys into a variable, but I'd obviously prefer to leave the PEM files where they are and just read their contents on request. Is there a lot of overhead from reading a file in the following manner?

```
$file = new SplFileObject('path/to/file');

while (!$file->eof()) {
    $content .= $file->fgets() 
}
```

I'm assuming the variables are stored in memory so they should be faster to read, but I wonder if it makes little to no difference in this case to read from a separate file.

FYI this would be called more or less on every request. Thank you!

Comment: Remember, in PHP the life cycle of a variable is only the duration of the scripts execution. So a matter of seconds, not for ever

Comment: good point! so what do you think?

Comment: So you dont have that choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a minimal difference, but the difference is negligible. Putting the data into the PHP-Code would be a micro (and premature) optimization and I strongly recommend, that you leave the keys in a separate file.

Also note: As far as I know, most operating systems cache files in memory, if they are read often.